# for loop unexceptional behaviour in C

Tags: c, for-loop

In c programming I write a code as below :
But the problem is first for loop not working properly, means the  for loop gets executed only 1 time not t times and some times when first for loop works  then output does  print yes or no only for l=1 and from l=2 to l=t ,it prints blank screen.

```
int t,i,n,arr[n+1],j,k,l,flag,x,y;
scanf("%d",&t);
for(l=1;l<=t;l++)
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for(k=1;k<n;k++)
    {
        for(j=k+1;j<n+1;j++)
        {
            if(arr[k]==arr[j])
            {
                flag=1;
            }
            else if(arr[k]!=arr[j])
            {
                x=arr[k];
                y=arr[j];
                if(arr[x]==arr[y])
                {
                    flag=2;
                    printf("YES");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(flag==2)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
        printf("NO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve], you didn't specify `arr` declaration. Indexing from `1` to `n+1` is certainly wrong, even if you initialized `arr` to have an additional element.

Comment: @Groo It's intentional I want to ignore the index =0 of array ,that's why I started from index=1;

Comment: I think we need a canonical dupe for how VLA work... Second question only today where someone used some nonsense value for the VLA size. Anyone know of a good duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible to diagnose without more context, but here's a huge red flag:

```
for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
```

You don't show the declaration of `arr`, but 1-indexing into an array is a very good way of shooting yourself in the foot. Remember that an N-element array in C has valid indexes of 0 to (N - 1), inclusive.

If the above overwrites the array, you get undefined behavior, which of course could make the outermost loop terminate early.

*UPDATE*: Now that you do show the declaration of `arr`, we can have a look:

```
int t,i,n,arr[n+1],j,k,l,flag,x,y;
```

This is ... very broken, since `n` is uninitialized at the point where it's being used in the VLA, this gives you undefined behavior. I'm actually a bit surprised your compiler accepted this. I tried building it on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) and it failed, saying:

```
error: ‘n’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
```

Perhaps you should upgrade your compiler too, and make sure you enable all warnings you can since you seem a bit unsure about the very basics of the language.

Comment: How can I initialize array if I do not want to use array[0]  and want to use from array[1] ?

Comment: @RoshanRai You could declare it with `array[N+1]` and just don't use `array[0]`, but it is not really good practice. Why do you even want to start with `1`?

Comment: @Osiris because I want to compare elements of array using its element as an array index .Assuming elements of array can  not be zero then how can I compare elements at array[0] even a single time ,that's why I want to start indexing from 1.

Comment: @unwind There is no problem in compilation . Have a look https://ideone.com/G6pxu4

Comment: @RoshanRai I think that's because you're building in "C", try setting the language to C99. Not sure what happens, since VLA:s were introduced in C99 it feels weird to use them in unspecified "C".

Answer (score 1):

Another problem is here:

```
int t,i,n,arr[n+1],j,k,l,flag,x,y;
//      ^     ^
//      |     |--- non initialized n used here
//      |     
//      |-- n declared here bot not initialized
```

when `arr[n+1]` is declared, the content of `n` is undetermined.

You probably want something like this:

```
int t,i,n,j,k,l,flag,x,y;

scanf("%d",&t);
for(l=1;l<=t;l++)
{
  scanf("%d",&t);
  for(l=1;l<=t;l++)
  {
      scanf("%d",&n);
      int arr[n+1];

      for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
      {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
      }
      ...
```

There are most likely more errors elsewhere. See also the other answer.